# Allow reverse SSH tunnel but not simple SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have a computer (let's name it A) behind a NAT, and I need a SSH connection to it from another computer (let's name it B).

I saw that I needed an SSH reverse tunnel, I tried, and it works.

In order to make the reverse tunnel work, I had to add the public key of A in the `authorized_keys` file of B.

The problem is that (for security concerns) I don't want computer A to be able to `ssh` in the computer B and see/modify the files in it (A is kind of a slave of B).

Is it possible to avoid this?

Comment: So someone bad might have physical access to A and you want to protect B?

Comment: @phk Yes, that's exactly my problem.

Comment: I might have simply suggested to you that the account on B for A to connect to would have to be very restricted so much that he can't do anything else (similar how you would do for a SCP-only server) but I am not sure myself how reliable that really is.

Comment: I thought about creating a chroot-jailed restricted user on B, but then, will I be able to connect from B to A with a non-restricted user even though the reverse tunnel is open for the restricted one ? (and how do I authorize A to connect only to the restricted user ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a computer (let's name it A) […] another computer (let's name it B). […] I had to add the public key of A in the `authorized_keys` file of B.

A common situation is to add the public key of particular *user* of A in the `auhorized_keys` file of particular *user* of B. It's not the key represents the whole computer A; similarly the `authorized_keys` file doesn't belong to the whole B.

You probably added the public key of some user `alpha` of A in the `authorized_keys` file of some user `beta` of B (the two users may use the same login, still they are on different machines, so let's keep distinct names `alpha` and `beta`).

My solution: set `beta`'s login shell on B to `/bin/false`. You can do this (on B) with `sudo usermod -s /bin/false beta`.

This would cause the following restrictions:

- `beta` cannot normally log into B at all; in particular `ssh beta@B` from A won't give anyone a shell, despite SSH authentication success;
- commands like `ssh beta@B whatever` won't succeed;
- neither SCP nor SFTP<sup>*</sup> trying to access `beta`'s account won't work (see [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9837/108618#comment27737_9839)).

It looks like there is no way for `alpha` on A to see or modify the files in B. However at the same time:

- anyone able to authorize as `beta` can use `ssh -N` to establish SSH connection to B without running any command there; this is an example command `alpha` should invoke on A:

  ```
    ssh -N -R 1234:127.0.0.1:22 beta@B
  ```
- you don't have to be `beta` to use the tunnel (although `-R` without specifying a bind address will bind only to the loopback interface of B, so you have to be *on B* to use the tunnel; see also [`man 5 sshd_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config), `GatewayPorts` option).

Additionally check `MaxSessions` and `PermitOpen` options in [`man 5 sshd_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config). I think if you use them properly then a possible attacker using `alpha`'s private key won't be able to "capture" too many ports on B.

---

* Exception: SFTP will work [without a functional shell](https://superuser.com/a/1585236/432690) if the server is configured to use [`Subsystem sftp internal-sftp`](https://serverfault.com/q/660160).