# SSH without sourcing .bashrc

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, terminal, bashrc

I was experimenting with my `.bashrc` file while remotely logged in to a server over SSH. I inadvertently left an `exit` in there that caused all subsequent logins to immediately disconnect. I was effectively locked out. I was able to recover access with intervention from someone with root privileges, but would it have been possible without help from someone else?

I tried doing stuff like running `ssh <server> 'bash --norc --noprofile'` and `ssh <server> 'mv .bashrc bashrc-backup'`, and even trying to forcibly overwrite it with `scp empty-file <server>:.bashrc`. However, all of these options seem to rely on first sourcing the broken `.bashrc` before running the command, so none of them worked.

It may well be the case that there is no way out of this kind of a situation. But is that by design? Is there a reason for why it's so easy to lock oneself out a system, e.g. just by running `ssh <server> 'echo exit > .bashrc'`? Are there ways to mitigate this kind of mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in the other answer, when an SSH client connects to the OpenSSH server, the OpenSSH server will generally start a shell session on the client's behalf, using the user's login shell:

1. If the client requests an interactive session, the server will launch the user's login shell.
2. If the client requests running a command, the server will use the user's login shell to run the command as a shell command.
3. Utilities like `scp`, `rsync`, and `git` which use ssh for transport will request a command to be run on the remote system, so they fall under #2.

If you have something in the remote user's shell startup files which causes the shell to exit, then you will have trouble getting in.

SFTP however is a special case. The OpenSSH server *may* be configured to support SFTP without launching an external command. *If* that's the case, then you'd be able to use sftp to connect to the server and delete, rename, or alter the `.bashrc` file which is causing the problem.

It depends on how the server is configured to support sftp. It can service sftp sessions by launching an external program (named [`sftp-server`](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp-server)). In this case you'd have the same problem getting in that you have with programs like `scp`. Or, the server can service sftp session by something referred to ["internal-sftp"](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#Subsystem), which doesn't require invoking a shell. It just depends on how the particular SSH server is configured.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this happens is because `sshd`, the server side component, invokes processes using your shell.  If it's spawning an interactive shell, it spawns it as a login shell; otherwise, it uses the `-c` argument to spawn a non-interactive shell to run the command you specify.

All of the operations you specified (specified commands and `scp`) are non-interactive operations, so normally bash would not load `.bashrc`, but bash has special-casing for when invoked by `sshd` so that it invokes it anyway.  If you were using zsh, then `.zshenv` (which is invoked for all shells) would be loaded, but `.zshrc` (which is only for interactive shells) would not be unless you were specifically loading a shell session.

In this case, if you're using bash, you're out of luck.  There isn't any way to invoke an SSH command on the server side without using the shell; this is true even for scp and sftp.  Most of the time, you want to use the shell because it sets up things like `PATH` for various programs, and it allows for a reasonable amount of scripting of complex commands, so OpenSSH always uses it.

This also has some security benefits: if you try to log into a system account that somehow has a valid password but a shell of `/usr/sbin/nologin` or `/bin/false`, then you can't do anything, which is probably what the system administrator intended.

There are ways to mitigate this.  Many people keep a Git repository of their dotfiles and develop them on one system, then deploy them to others.  For example, I always do dotfile development on my laptop.  Presumably you'd notice this problem a little sooner if any time you opened a new terminal window it immediately exited, and you might have root access to fix it yourself.

If you need to test a configuration which might lock you out, such as shell configuration or a `sudoers` change, you can leave one shell (normal or root, respectively) open and then do some testing, so if you break something, you still have a way in to undo it.